# Clojure - add file to the classpath

Tags: clojure, classpath, clojurescript

How do I add resources (preferably programmatically) to the classpath of my program ?

I am using [`compojure.route.resources`](https://weavejester.github.io/compojure/compojure.route.html) like the following :

> A route for serving resources on the classpath. Accepts the following
>   keys:   :root       - the root prefix path of the resources, defaults
>   to 'public'   :mime-types - an optional map of file extensions to mime
>   types

```
(defroutes routes
  (resources "/js" {:root "js"})
  (resources "/css" {:root "css"}))
```

Now I would like to add files to be served, but I don't know where to generate them.

*Note :* in case it matters, I am using [`boot`](http://boot-clj.com/) and the example is taken from [this template](https://github.com/Deraen/saapas/blob/master/src/clj/backend/server.clj#L13-L15).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regular boot based project, you can have a resources folder at the root:

```
-rw-r--r--@  1 niko  staff   173 Dec 18 10:19 boot.properties
-rw-r--r--@  1 niko  staff  2796 Dec 30 09:55 build.boot
drwxr-xr-x@ 17 niko  staff   578 Dec 30 10:49 resources
drwxr-xr-x@  4 niko  staff   136 Nov 16 09:52 src
drwxr-xr-x@ 17 niko  staff   578 Jan 14 11:50 target
```

In that folder you can create the css and the js folder and include your files there:

```
drwxr-xr-x@ 5 niko  staff  170 Dec 14 15:33 resources/css/
drwxr-xr-x@ 4 niko  staff  136 Nov 30 18:01 resources/js/
```

Comment: That was my understanding as well. Now the reason I am asking this is because I am using this project as a template, and running it locally I don't see any `resources` folder. The path has been modified : https://github.com/Deraen/saapas/blob/master/build.boot#L5 ,  but it is not pointing to the `css` folder. Hence the impression that I am missing something.